# Finding Big O Estimate

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I've got a homework problem where I have to find the smallest order big o of several functions. The first question is as follows:

```
F(n)=5n^5-4n^4+3n^3
```

I believe the correct answer is n^5 because that is the slowest growing function that is still the same order as F but grows slower.

There are a few things I don't understand though. First, how would I show my work for this? It's a sort of intuitive thing.

Second, I'm confused on the notation. If I say F is O(G), does that mean F is big o of G or F is big o to G?

I'm struggling to wrap my head around this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may find the "example" on wikipedia for big o notation helpful. It discusses exactly this sort of problem. And yes, I think you are right in $F(n)$ is $O(n^5)$. Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example